# QtQuick QML How to highlight item in ListView on hover?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the following QML:

```
menuBar: MenuBar {...}
header: ToolBar {...}
SplitView {
    id: splitView
    ...
    Item {
        SplitView.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2
        Component {
            id: modDelegate
            GridLayout {
                id: modGrid; columns: 2; columnSpacing: 30
                MouseArea {
                    z: 0; anchors.fill: parent; hoverEnabled: true
                    onEntered: ???; onExited: ???
                }
                CheckBox {}
                ColumnLayout {
                    Layout.topMargin: 5
                    Text {...}; Text {...}; Text {...}; Text {...}
                }
            }
        }
        ListView {
            id: modList; anchors.fill: parent; model: ModModel {}; delegate: modDelegate; focus: true
        }
        Layout.fillHeight: true
    }
    Item {
        SplitView.preferredWidth: parent.width / 2
        ...
    }
}
```

I want when I hover over an item of that ListView, that item to be visually highlighted (without preventing me from clicking the checkbox inside it of course).

Comment: did you have a look at `highlight` property of the `ListView`? it basically highlights the `currentIndex`.

Comment: My problem was that I couldn't find how to set the `currentIndex` to the item's index that I hover on. But I just found info in another question's answer on how to set the `currentIndex` to the selected index. I just didn't saw anything in the docs about being able to use `index` in the delegate to access the current item index. So with that I solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to solve this in another unrelated question's answer.
I didn't saw anywhere in the docs anything mentioning that I can get the index of the item/delegate I'm in just by using `index` from inside the delegate.
So I just wrapped everything inside `modDelegate` into `Item` and set the `MouseArea`'s `onEntered` property to `modList.currentIndex = index`